# Decimal Thousand Separator and Decimal Point

Tags: c#, string, decimal

I googled the web for hours but couldn't find my answer. I need when a user types or copies any number in TextBox then the number should follow the bellow rules:

1. Only one decimal point should be permitted.
2. Thousand Separator.
3. Trailing zeros should be removed. I mean the zeros after decimal point should NOT be displayed.

**Update**
For example,

> 123 => 123
>
> 1234.00 => 1,234
>
> 123456.05 => 123,456.05
>
> 123456.50 => 123,456.5

How can I do this?

Comment: Hmya, why don't you just assume that a human is capable of typing a number.  The vast majority of the world population knows how to do that.  Treat them with respect and they'll return the favor.  Only check *after* he entered it, using the Validating event.

Comment: Can you be clear as to *exactly* what format? Give an example of precisely what it should look like. For example, you say 'Thousand Separator', but which one? a comma?

Comment: You might also try a MaskedTextBox, I think it was meant for limiting user input. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Comment: I updated my question and gave some examples.

Comment: Why do you need this? If you need to store it somewhere then so long as you can parse the text to a decimal you can do whatever formatting you like.

Comment: @GER - make that an answer! I think `MaskedTextBox` sounds like exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: If you simply need client side validation that their input is a number then this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to try to parse value as a number.

```
decimal value;
if(decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value)
{
   //value is ok
   textBox.Text = string.Format("{0}", value);//If you want some fancier formatting
}
else
{
    //Value is not valid
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `decmial`, otherwise some entries would get changed to slightly different numbers since `double` cannot exactly store all decimal numbers.

Comment: How should I format it so that it be displayed as I need?

Comment: @MohsenJafari Change a "string.Format" to this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dn906224(v=vs.110).aspx Juharr: fixed.